# Antialiasing and texture filtering in native Android application using OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I am mapping a 360 degree photospheric image on a sphere with camera at centre of sphere. When we build the application using native Android SDK and OpenGL ES 2.0, we see jaggy edges like the one shown in below image. The jags are visible on the arms of sofa, edges of floor etc.  when I see this view using cardboard device

On the other hand, the same image ( 4096X2048 resolution) is rendered perfectly in unity3d application for Android.

The magnification and minification filter for the texture that we are using is GL_LINEAR.

Source Code used for setting filtering paramenters for texture and generating Texture and mipmap:

```
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mSphereTextureIds[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Code for Multisample Antialiasing ( 4X MSAA)

```
cardboardView.setEGLConfigChooser(new MyConfigChooser());
cardboardView.setRenderer(renderer);
```

I have also turned on 4x Multisample anti aliasing. But even after doing this, there are jags inside texture. I used highp precision for both float and int in both of my shaders.

```
class MyConfigChooser implements CardboardView.EGLConfigChooser {
    @Override
    public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {
        int attribs[] = {
            EGL10.EGL_LEVEL, 0,
            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4,  // EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT
            EGL10.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL10.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
            EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
            EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,
            EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES, 2,  // This is for 4x MSAA.
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] configCounts = new int[1];
        egl.eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, configs, 1, configCounts);

        if (configCounts[0] == 0) {
            // Failed! Error handling.
            Log.d("test","MSAA Failed............");
            return null;
        } else {
            return configs[0];
        }
    }
```

Is there some post processing that Unity does on the textures for filtering during magnification that gives it a better look without aliasing effect ?
Can we do anisotropic filtering to smoothen the texture on magnification without blurring on Android ? If yes can we get a clue on how to do that ?
Is 4X the maximum MSAA that is currently supported on Android ? (I am using Nexus 5).

Thanks in advance

Apurv Nigam

Comment: Can you include an image? Or at least link it from an external site if you don't have permission to include it directly?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do anisotropic filtering to smoothen the texture on
>   magnification without blurring on Android?

Not in general - it's "really expensive" so not much mobile hardware supports it.

> If yes can we get a clue on how to do that?

There is no support for it in "official" OpenGL ES; check the vendor extensions to see if one exists. For desktop GL it is supported via the GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic extension - I've not seen a mobile GPU supporting it.

> Is 4X the maximum MSAA that is currently supported on Android? (I am
>   using Nexus 5).

Depends on vendor - some devices support 8x (Mali-T760), some older devices don't support it at all (Tegra-1/2/3) - so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Isogen for the response. But is there any method I can reduce the pixelation effect in my textured sphere.I feel like the texture is minified while I am showing. Can I do something to restrict it to be shown only in its original size without minification or magnification ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. I figured out that the image was being scaled down by Universal Image Loader library being used by me. So the bitmap that was being given to texImage2D call was already scaled down causing a pixelated texture. So I decoded my image using BitmapFactory using isScaled=false option.